# Errors trying to run a maven project from the Command Line

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, command-line

I am really struggling trying to get my maven project to run in the command line. It runs how I want it to in eclipse, but using mvn package command in the terminal runs the unit tests that I wrote, but not the actual main source code application that I want it to run.

```
java -cp target/TestKata-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.techelevator.Main
```

Returns this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/OkHttpClient
    at com.techelevator.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.OkHttpClient
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 1 more
```

I assume I'm getting this error, because the dependencies are not included in the SNAPSHOT.jar file and it fails after it gets to the first line where a dependency is required?? Any help is greatly appreciated, I am very new to this stuff so I apologize if I'm doing something really stupid.

EDIT: 
Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.techelevator</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestKata</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
            <version>2.0rc2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehouse.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.techelevator.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you share your pom ?

Comment: can you share the `dependencies` section of your `pom.xml` please

Comment: added the pom.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must package your dependencies into your jar via maven-assemble-plugin.the `jar-with-dependnecies` descriptor find in [maven](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

you can add executions when you run `mvn package` command,that will output a jar filename like `*-with-jar-dependencies.jar` and then run that jar file instead via `java`,e.g:`java -cp target/TestKata-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-with-jar-dependencies.jar com.techelevator.Main`

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assembly</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: So I added the plugin, and I think "mvn package" should be creating the jar target/TestKata-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar ? It still seems to create the normal target/TestKata-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar only. Am I supposed to be running a different command once I put the plugin in the pom.xml file?

Comment: I got it working!!! Thank you so much!! This has had me stuck for hours.